# Split one background image into two divs

Tags: html, css

Hello stackoweflow community, I need help, I'am creating website and I need split image in the half, but they must be divs.. Is it possible to split background-image into the half to be two divs? Hese is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hLt5rguq/6/
Here is the html code how I need it to look like:

```
<div class="wallpaper">
    <div class="left-side"></div>
    <div class="right-side"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about cut your image with some image editor (even paint) and set background-image to `left-side` and `right-side`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, you just have to cut it into 2 elements and position the background. I've used `.wallpaper` to show the previous image

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wallpaper {
  background: transparent url("http://intrawallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/awesome-rain-wallpaper_0.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px; //spacing
}
.left-side {
  float: left;
  background: transparent url("http://intrawallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/awesome-rain-wallpaper_0.jpg") no-repeat scroll 0 top;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px; //show cutting edge
}
.right-side {
  float: left;
  background: transparent url("http://intrawallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/awesome-rain-wallpaper_0.jpg") no-repeat scroll -250px top;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-side"></div>
<div class="right-side"></div>
<div class="wallpaper"></div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLt5rguq/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS out which should fix your problem

```
.left-side, .right-side { 
    width: 50%; 
    float: left; 
    display: inline-block; 
    height: inherit; 
    background-color: transparent; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do it using css, here is the example using one image spilt into two divs using below code

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.wallpaper {
    width:1024px;
    height:683px;
    display:block;
}
.left-side{
     background: transparent url("http://intrawallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/awesome-rain-wallpaper_0.jpg") no-repeat left top; 
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
.right-side{
     background: transparent url("http://intrawallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/awesome-rain-wallpaper_0.jpg") no-repeat right top; 
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
}
```